# Oracle API: What APIs are used for the oracle iExpense application

Tags: oracle

I am trying to find out what API's are used for the iExpense application when creating an expense report. I tried looking for these online but no luck. I wish to use these APIs in my mobile application.

Can anyone suggest ways to find out the same

Answer (score 0):

Oracle iExpense is a part of the whole Oracle Application suit of products i.e. an ERP. I don't think you would find an iExpense API anywhere other than on an existing licensed installation of Oracle Apps where iExpense is being used. Even if you find one, you would end up writing your own API with the logics driven off of the base API's in iExpense.